# How to upload MERN Stack application on vps?

Tags: mongodb, web-deployment, mern, vps

Hi everyone I have mern stack application which is working fine on local host but when I try to upload online

1. It displays home page but donot accept credentials that I enter
2. It does show me success message on port number that I authenticate
   But the problem is It does not connects with mongo db though I have installed mongo db on my vps but does not store value or neither give any output on console.
3. Its not navigating to next page after validation and here is what it displays on console

`POST http://phasermag.com:2000/login net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Can any body guide me with this scenario.

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you forgot the .env file in the backend. Find it and check it out.

Comment: @TranQuocBao I have admin panel database working on same domain All I need is to fetch data from admin panel